# Environment Variables in React application

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, production-environment

I want to add a .env file in my React application.
The project wasn't created using Create React APP. And without Webpack.
I'm struggling to find a proper solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a easy solution you could try to use [react-app-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-env).

You could folllow [this](https://tacomanator.medium.com/environments-with-create-react-app-7b645312c09d) simple guide. In brief:

1. install it:

   ```
   yarn add --dev react-app-env (or npm install --save-dev react-app-env)
   ```
2. change the start and build scripts:

   ```
   "scripts": {
     "start": "react-app-env start'",
     "build": "react-app-env build'",
     "test": "react-app-env test'",
     ...
   }
   ```
3. finally add at least two configuration files (on project root folder): `development.env` and `production.env`. By default `development.env` is used imported on `npm start` and `npm test`, and `production.env` on `npm build`.